# BackgroundTasks and BGTaskScheduler on SwiftUI not firing

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, background-task

I am trying to setup some `BackgroundTasks` to run some code periodically (say once every day) while the app is closed. I believe the `BackgroundTasks` API on swift is just for that? (Please let me know if I'm mistaken). I followed the article [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/using_background_tasks_to_update_your_app) on Apple's Docs to implement it, and adjusting it to fit SwiftUI.

**Problem**: The background task never fires but is "pending" (as seen in the images)

**Disclaimer**: I did add the `Background Modes` capability and checked `Background fetch` and also `Background processing`, and added the identifer to the `Info.plist`

**Code**:

`Main` - Setup app delegate, get scene, set UserDefaults counter, button to get all pending tasks, text showing the UserDefault counter, Button to add to UserDefault counter, call the `schedule()` task when app enters background

```
import SwiftUI
import BackgroundTasks

@main
struct GyfterApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scene
    @AppStorage("test") var test = 1
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            VStack {
                Button("Test") {
                    BGTaskScheduler.shared.getPendingTaskRequests { all in
                        print("Pending Tasks Requests", all)
                    }
                }
                Text("\(test)")
                Button("ADD") {
                    test = test + 1
                }
            }
                .onChange(of: scene) { newValue in
                    switch newValue {
                    case .background:
                        print("Entered Background")
                        appDelegate.schedule()
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

`Operation` - Operation for the `BackgroundTasks`, it prints a message and adds 1 to the UserDefaults counter

```
class OP: Operation {
    @AppStorage("test") var test = 1
    
    override func main() {
        print("OPERATION RAN")
        test = test + 1
    }
}
```

`AppDelegate` -

- Register task with given identifier, print message when it runs, and print the output of the register call to see if it was registered (it gets registered but doest not call `handleSchedule(task:)`)
- Schedule the task request with identifier, for 60 seconds ahead, submit to the scheduler (`schedule()` only gets called when app enters background, not when `handleSchedule(task:)` is supposed to fire which never gets called)
- handleSchedule(task:) print statement, call `schedule()`, create `OperationQueue`, create `Operation`, set `expirationHandler` and `setTaskCompleted`, add operation to the queue

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    @AppStorage("test") var test = 1
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        print("LAUNCHED")
        let a = BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "IDENTIFIER", using: nil) { task in
            print("REGISTERED")
            self.test = self.test + 1
            self.handleSchedule(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
        }
        print(a)
        return true
    }
    
     func schedule() {
        let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "IDENTIFIER")
        request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60)
        
       do {
          try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
       } catch {
          print("Could not schedule app refresh: \(error)")
       }
    }
    
     func handleSchedule(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
        print("HANDLING SCHEDULE")
        schedule()
        
        let queue = OperationQueue()
        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
        
        let operation = OP()

        
        task.expirationHandler = {
            print("BG Task Expired")
            queue.cancelAllOperations()
        }
        
        operation.completionBlock = {
            print("OPERATION COMPLETED")
            task.setTaskCompleted(success: !operation.isCancelled)
        }
        
        queue.addOperation(operation)
    }
}
```

**Console log**: Display of the print statements from the function calls

- Line 1: App launched
- Line 2: `BGTaskScheduler` "registered" (supposedly) the task with identifier
- Line 3: Array of the pending tasks
- Line 4: App entered background (and `schedule()` got called)
- Line 5: Array of the pending tasks

```
LAUNCHED
true
Pending Tasks Requests []
Entered Background
Pending Tasks Requests [<BGAppRefreshTaskRequest: INDENTIFIER, earliestBeginDate: 2022-02-28 02:57:50 +0000>]
```

Comment: did u get any solution for this issue?
i am facing same scenario

Comment: @MahmoudZinji I never got a solution for this

Comment: @BlueStarXD Just to make sure. Did you try debugging this on a real device (not simulator)?

Answer (score 0):

I would debug this first by forcing the background task to run on device so you know its succeeding:
`e -l objc -- (void)[[BGTaskScheduler sharedScheduler] _simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER"]`

However, my hunch is that your operation queue is simply being deallocated as you leave scope since it's not hooked up to anything. Possibly you need to `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()` to ensure this code doesn't exit scope with a queue'd operation.